# continuous x categorical interaction (repeated measures), no interaction but simple slope analysis shows interaction

Tags: categorical-data, interaction, continuous-data, predictor

My model is a 2-level repeated within-subject factor (Repeated), a between-subject factor (Condition) and a covariate (Difference).

When I ran a Bayesian RM ANCOVA in JASP all seems to make sense, except for that there was strong evidence against the interaction between Difference (continuous) and Repeated (categorical: Repeated 1 & Repeated 2).
[image: Bayesian RM ANCOVA]

The thing is when I plot the data I could see there's difference between the two lines. So I ran two separate Bayesian linear regressions to double-check. And indeed:
There's no effect of Difference on Repeated 1.
But there's an effect of Difference on Repeated 2.
My question is then: why did I find that there's no evidence for the interaction between Difference and Repeated in the RM ANCOVA? Which result should I trust?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The interaction tests if there is evidence that the two slopes are different from *one another.*
2. Looking at there being an effect of Repeated 1 but not Repeated 2 tells you that there is evidence that Repeated 1 is not different from *zero*, while there is evidence that Repeated 2 is different from *zero*.

The tests are just making different comparisons: The interaction asks, "Are these two slopes different from one another?" The simple slopes analyses ask, "Is this slope different from zero?" What can happen is: One slope *is* different form zero, the other is *not* different from zero, but they both are not different from *one another*.

Which one should you trust? It depends on your research question: Are you interested in a difference between slopes? Then the interaction term is what you want to look at. Are you interested in each of the two is different from zero? Then you should look at the simple slopes. Traditionally, people do not examine the simple slopes unless the interaction is "significant" (I'm aware you're in a Bayesian framework here, but that's the traditional approach, which employs NHST).

Comment: Thanks Mark! (I do not have enough reputation points to upvote your answer.)